# How to convert GPU TextureFrame to bitmap in android mediapipe

Tags: java, android, mediapipe

What I'm trying to achieved is to get the mediapipe frame output and modify it like adding overlay and other stuffs then send it back to mediapipe, but unfortunately I'm getting white blank in the bitmap image.

I tried to see check [here (FrameProcessor.java)](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/java/com/google/mediapipe/components/FrameProcessor.java) if they are some way they converted the gpu frame to bitmap but there's none!

```
class MyTextureConsumer implements TextureFrameConsumer {
    private final FrameProcessor processor;
    private final Context context;
    private int aa=0;

    MyTextureConsumer(Context context, FrameProcessor processor) {
        this.context = context;
        this.processor = processor;
    }
    @Override
    public void onNewFrame(TextureFrame frame) {
        // Get GPU texture id
        int textureId = frame.getTextureName();

        int[] frameBuffer = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, frameBuffer, 0);
        GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer[0]);

        GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(
                GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId, 0);

        // Bind the FBO and read the texture into a ByteBuffer
        GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer[0]);

        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(frame.getWidth() * frame.getHeight() * 4); // RGBA format
        buffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight(), GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

        // Create a Bitmap from the ByteBuffer
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        buffer.rewind();
        bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);

        saveBitmapToGallery(bitmap); // I'm getting blank white bitmap image
        // Release OpenGL resources
        GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        GLES20.glDeleteFramebuffers(1, frameBuffer, 0);

        // Create a Canvas for drawing on the bitmap
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        // Define circle properties (position and radius)
        int centerX = frame.getWidth() / 2;
        int centerY = frame.getHeight() / 2;
        int radius = Math.min(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight()) / 4; // Adjust the radius as needed

        // Create a Paint object for drawing the circle
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED); // Circle color
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        // Draw a filled circle on the bitmap
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, paint);

        // Convert the modified bitmap back to a ByteBuffer
        ByteBuffer editedByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(frame.getWidth() * frame.getHeight() * 4); // ARGB_8888 format
        bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(editedByteBuffer);
        Bitmap editedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        editedByteBuffer.rewind();
        editedBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(editedByteBuffer);



        Packet imagePacket = processor.getPacketCreator().createRgbImageFrame(editedBitmap);

        try {
            //processor.getGraph().addConsumablePacketToInputStream("input_video", imagePacket, frame.getTimestamp());
        } catch (MediaPipeException var10) {
            Log.e("FrameProcessor", "Mediapipe error: ", var10);
        }
        
        System.out.println("========================================");
        System.out.println("NEW FRAME");
        System.out.println("===================s=====================");
        imagePacket.release();
        frame.release();
    }
    private void saveBitmapToGallery(Bitmap bitmap) {
        aa++;
        if(aa < 45 || aa > 50) return;
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "my_image.png");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");

        Uri uri = context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

        try {
            OutputStream fos = context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```